# new C learner. why is below code not working. I am getting wrong answers for both feet and inches

Tags: c

I am trying to run this program to convert meters into feet and inches. Using 3 meters
    as an example I should be getting 9 feet and 10.11 inches. I am newbie and tried to use
    fgets and still struggling to finish this using modf as the assignment. In below code I
    am using modff as this was recommended to be used with float variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void metersToFeetAndInches(double meters, unsigned int *feetPtr, double *inPtr)
{
        float rawfeet = meters * 3.281;
        float feet;
        double rawinches = modff(rawfeet, &feet);


        if (feetPtr){
                printf("Storing %1.0f to feet at the address %p\n", feet, feetPtr);
                feet= *feetPtr;
        }

        if (inPtr){
                printf("Storing %0.5f to  inches at the address %p\n", rawinches, inPtr);
                *inPtr = rawinches;}

}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

        double meters;
        double inches;
        unsigned int feet;

        printf("How many meters are you trying to convert?\n");

        scanf("%lf%*[^\n]",(&meters), stdin);


        metersToFeetAndInches(meters, &feet, &inches);
        printf("%1.0f meters is equal to %u feet and %.3f inches.\n", meters,feet, inches);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `feet= *feetPtr;` --> `*feetPtr = feet;`

Comment: `double rawinches = modff(rawfeet, &feet);`-->`double rawinches = modff(rawfeet, &feet)*12.0;` **1 feet == 12 inch**.

Comment: `scanf("%lf%*[^\n]",(&meters), stdin);` --> `scanf("%lf%*[^\n]",&meters);`

Comment: Any reason you are using lower precision for your calculations than is passed in?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"

void metersToFeetAndInches(float meters, float *feetsPtr, float *inchesPtr)
{
    *inchesPtr = modff(meters * 3.28084, feetsPtr) * 12;
}


int main()
{
    float meters;
    float feet;
    float inches;

    printf("How many meters are you trying to convert?\n");
    fscanf(stdin, "%f%*[^\n]", &meters);

    metersToFeetAndInches(meters, &feet, &inches);
    printf("%.3f meters is equal to %1.0f feet and %.3f inches.\n",
           meters, feet, inches);
    return 0;
}
```

Some remarks:

- It is better to use the same unit throughout for calculations (here float).
- You forgot to convert fractional feet to inches.